# How can I run a file from Win+R command without typing the complete address?

Tags: windows

I have a file pass.xls which I use frequently. 
Is there ant way I can open this file from Win+R command by just typing the name and not the complete address?

Comment: The only true way to accomplish this would be to add the path to the folder which contains the file to your PATH variable.

Comment: which version of Windows do you use? From Windows 7 you can type also after pressing just the windows key and that search is much more powerful.

Comment: @DavidPostill, are you asking to type the file name in run box(without its path) & it will find the file itself if the drive is indexed ? Never seen that work but would be great if it would

Comment: @DavidPostill, I thought you meant to type the file name in run

Answer (score 2):

Move your file (*pass.xls*) to Windows Folder, usually *** C:\Windows\ *** . Finished!
Now type **pass.xls** in RUN window ( <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ) , and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key :)

instead of move your file, It's better to create a shortcut, and move shortcut file to WinDir. then type ***ShortcutName.LNK*** in RUN window.

> **Note:** if you can't find your windows folder, type **%windir%** in run window, then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you will get it.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I run a file from the Windows menu without typing the complete address?

> Is there any way I can open this file from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command by just typing the name and not the complete address?

It is much easier to use the **Search Box** for this:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>.
2. Start typing the filename (the keys entered will go into the **Search** box).
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the matching file appears.
4. Excel (or LibreOffice) will open the file.

   [image]

Note:

- Indexing must be enabled for this to work.

---

#### The search box

> The search box is one of the most convenient ways to find things on
> your computer. The exact location of the items doesn't matter—the
> search box will scour your programs and all of the folders in your
> personal folder (which includes Documents, Pictures, Music, Desktop,
> and other common locations). It will also search your e‑mail messages,
> saved instant messages, appointments, and contacts. Picture of the
> search box on the Start menu The Start menu search box
>
> [image]
>
> To use the search box, open the Start menu and start typing. You don't
> need to click inside the box first. As you type, the search results
> appear above the search box in the left pane of the Start menu.
>
> A program, file, or folder will appear as a search result if:
>
> - Any word in its title matches or begins with your search term.
> - Any text in the actual contents of the file (such as the text in a word-processing document) matches or begins with your search term.
> - Any word in a property of the file, such as the author, matches or begins with your search term. (For more information about file
>   properties, see Change the properties for a file.)
>
> Click any search result to open it. Or, click the Clear button Picture
> of the search box Clear button on the Start menu to clear the search
> results and return to the main programs list. You can also click See
> more results to search your entire computer.
>
> Besides searching programs, files and folders, and communications, the
> search box also looks through your Internet favorites and the history
> of websites you've visited. If any of these webpages include the
> search term, they appear under a heading called "Files."

Source [The Start menu (overview)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/improve-windows-searches-using-index-faq#1TC=windows-7)

---

#### Further reading

- [The Start menu (overview)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/improve-windows-searches-using-index-faq#1TC=windows-7)
- [Improve Windows searches using the index: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/improve-windows-searches-using-index-faq#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WIN+R follow these steps:

1. Use only WIN
2. Then write the name of the file
3. Press `Tab`
4. Press `Enter`

Comment: This is also an option, essentially just a search for the file though...

Answer (score 0):

Add a environment variable (like eg. %appdata%) to the folder with a file and then do

Win+R %myenv%/myfile.ext

How to add env var:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299591/how-to-create-a-custom-percent-shortcut-like-appdata)